# How does vim know if register contents were from a linewise selection when pasting?

Tags: vimscript, cut-copy-paste

I haven't been able to find documentation on how vim knows if register contents came from a linewise-selection vs characterwise or blockwise selection.

For example, given the text below:

```
Hello there my name is Markus
and I went to the store to buy
bananas and motor oil
```

If I select the first line in linewise visual mode, yank it to a specific register, and save the register contents to a file, the register contents are only what I had selected:

[image: Nothing special about register contents]

Now, if I then reload the unnamed register (`@"`) with the contents of `/tmp/output.txt`, and paste it, it pastes as if I had selected it in characterwise or blockwise visual mode:

[image]

I have to assume that vim is tracking how register contents are set, and that if it is done directly from a yank/cut/delete/etc., it saves which visual mode it was done in.

That being said, how *exactly* does that work? I'm working on a plugin, and I'd like to be able to tell vim to paste text as if they were originally copied in linewise or characterwise visual mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `getregtype()` to get a register's type (characterwise, linewise, blockwise).

```
echo getregtype('a')
```

This will yield, `v`, `V`, or `<c-v>` for the `"a` register.

For more help see:

```
:h getregtype()
:h getreg()
:h setreg()
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what I was looking for. Also, I forgot about setreg, I'd only been using `let @X = "val"`. Double thanks!